# Number of connections to Kafka boot strap server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have two topics with 10 partition on each and I am using below code to listen to messages. Here how many connections will establish ? is it 20?
Does each connection will be at partition level or namespace (bootstarap server) level ?

```
@Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
```

---

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${spring.kafka.topics}'.split(',')}",
            concurrency = "20",
            clientIdPrefix = "client123",
            groupId = "group123")
    public void listen(final ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> inputEvent) throws Exception {
        handleMessage(inputEvent);
    }
```

Comment: any updates on this? did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

concurrency represents the number of threads; each thread creates a Consumer; they run in parallel, each consumer is responsible for partitions in topics, in your case you will start 20 consumer threads which will read from two topics, in the same consumer groups, because you have only 10 partitions per topic, then you will have 10 threads that will probably won't get partitions assigned and be idle.